# Keyboard disappears on focus in Mobile Browsers (iOS + Android)

Tags: javascript, mobile, keyboard, shopify

Please help me find and fix this bug https://www.screencast.com/t/mzpKCY4OXH

On the video iPhone X with iOs 11.4.1

This is Shopify Store. Bug hide keyboard for all input on site: in checkouts, in the subscription form. And client says me what bug repeats also on Galaxy S9 in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like textfield lost their firstResponder. 
Not sure but
When you focus on a specific texfield 
Set the textField as firstResponder.

Check this two. 
textFieldShouldBeginEditing
textFieldDidBeginEditing

Comment: It's not the native app. it's a web site on Shopify.